# BotFramework: DialogState / DialogStack never getting populated

Tags: typescript, azure, botframework, azure-cosmosdb, azure-bot-service

We have a simple bot that is using dialogs, it works fine but I recently changed it to use CosmosDB for the state storage and we have now noticed that the dialogStack is empty.

Most of the code for the bot was taken from the BotFramework example found in the [samples repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/19.custom-dialogs/bot.js).

The user state is being accurately updated per message, the initialisation code looks like this:

```
this.dialogState = conversationState.createProperty(DIALOG_STATE_PROPERTY);
this.dialogAccessor = userState.createProperty(DIALOG_PROPERTY);

this.dialogs = new DialogSet(this.dialogState);
this.dialogs.add(new GreetingDialog(GREETING_DIALOG, this.dialogAccessor));
this.dialogs.add(new PharmacyOrderDialog(PHARMACY_DIALOG, this.dialogAccessor));

this.conversationState = conversationState;
this.userState = userState;
```

We are calling the saveChanges function at the end of onTurn:

```
await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);
```

I can't find any info on what should even be in the dialogStack object, nevermind a solution to what I assume is a bug in our code.

Thanks for any help.

Edit, adding onTurn function for more clarity:

```
public onTurn = async (context: TurnContext) => {
if (context.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
  if (context.activity.value) {
    let useridFromCard = context.activity.value.useridList;
    if (context.activity.value.useridList) {
      useridFromCard = context.activity.value.useridList;
    }
    await this.dialogAccessor.set(context, new DialogDetails(useridFromCard));
  }

  let dialogResult: DialogTurnResult;
  const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(context);
  const results = await this.luisRecognizer.recognize(context);
  const topIntent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(results);

  const dialogDetails: DialogDetails = await this.dialogAccessor.get(context);
  if (!dialogDetails) {
    await this.dialogAccessor.set(context, new DialogDetails(ENVIRONMENT.USERID, results));
  } else {
    dialogDetails.luisResults = results;
    await this.dialogAccessor.set(context, dialogDetails);
  }
  const interrupted = await this.isTurnInterrupted(dc, results);
  if (interrupted) {
    if (dc.activeDialog !== undefined) {
      await dc.repromptDialog();
    }
  } else {
    dialogResult = await dc.continueDialog();
  }

  if (!dc.context.responded) {
    switch (dialogResult.status) {
      case DialogTurnStatus.empty:
        switch (topIntent) {
          case GREETING_INTENT:
            await dc.beginDialog(GREETING_DIALOG);
            break;
          case PHARMACY_INTENT:
            await dc.beginDialog(PHARMACY_DIALOG);
            break;
          case NONE_INTENT:
            await context.sendActivities(ResponseRandomizer.getRandomResponse(RANDOM_PHRASE_PATH, POST_GREETING_MESSAGE_PHRASE_KEY));
            break;
          default:
            await dc.context.sendActivity("I didn't understand what you just said to me.");
            break;
        }
        break;
      case DialogTurnStatus.waiting:
        // The active dialog is waiting for a response from the user, so do nothing.
        break;
      case DialogTurnStatus.complete:
        // All child dialogs have ended. so do nothing.
        break;
      default:
        // Unrecognized status from child dialog. Cancel all dialogs.
        await dc.cancelAllDialogs();
        break;
    }
  }
} else if (context.activity.type === ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate) {
  if (context.activity.membersAdded.length !== 0) {
    for (const idx in context.activity.membersAdded) {
      if (context.activity.membersAdded[idx].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
        const welcomeCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(WelcomeCard);
        await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [welcomeCard] });

        await context.sendActivities(ResponseRandomizer.getRandomResponse
          (RANDOM_PHRASE_PATH, WELCOME_MESSAGE_PHRASE_KEY));
        const useridCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(USERIDCard);
        await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [useridCard] });

      }
    }
  }
}
await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);
await this.userState.saveChanges(context);
}
```

Appreciate the help all. It may just be that there never needs to be anything stored in there with how our bot is currently set up but I just want to ensure it's not an error on our end.

Comment: I agree with Drew's "answer", that you should update your question with your `onTurn` code. I've also seen this issue pop up with Cosmos, especially with the new partition system. Can you also update your question with the code you use to set up Cosmos storage in `index.js`? Are you using `cosmosDbStorage` from `botbuilder-azure`? And is your CosmosDB set up with a partition key?

Comment: I've also run into this issue when attempting to use two different storage sources at the same time (which maybe you're doing since you're testing out Cosmos?). If you're doing so, use `await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context, true);`, which forces it send the update.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? If so, and one of these answers helped, can you mark it as "answered" so I can close this ticket in my support tracker? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, the dialog state (its stack et. al.) is really just a black box as far as your own code is concerned. All you should have to do is make sure that you are saving the state container that you created the property for the dialog state in which, according to what you've said above, you are (i.e. `this.conversationState.saveChanges(context)`).

I would need to see how you are actually invoking the dialogs. Can you update your question with what your `onTurn` method looks like... at least with respect to your invocation of the dialogs?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a `dialogStack` if you're using either a `DialogSet` or `WaterfallDialog`. Here's [conceptual information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#using-dialogs) about dialogs and the [SDK reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/dialogset?view=botbuilder-ts-latest). The `dialogStack` for [Sample 19](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/19.custom-dialogs/bot.js) looks like this:

[image]

I don't see anything wrong in your initialization/constructor code, although it is a little unconventional since it uses `dialogState` *and* `dialogAccessor`. Shouldn't be an issue, however.

Your `onTurn` code also looks fine, as far as I can tell.

This leads me to believe one of two things:

1. You're looking at `dialogStack` when there aren't any active dialogs. The `dialogStack` is only populated when the user is presented with dialogs and then it's cleared out at the end of the dialog. It doesn't sound like your bot is having issues, so I'm guessing this is the case.
2. Whichever dialog is giving you issues (GreetingDialog or PharmacyOrderDialog) isn't properly invoking prompts.

Possible fixes for #2, above:

1. You're adding `dialogDetails` to your `userState` and then passing your `userState` to each of your dialogs. You're not invoking the prompts off of `dialogDetails` from your `userState`, are you? If so, that could be an issue. If you *are* doing this, your `dialogStack` might be appearing in `userState` instead of `conversationState`, which wouldn't be optimal. The only context you should be using for dialogs/prompts/waterfallDialogs is the one derived from `conversationState`, like in your `this.dialogState = conversationState.createProperty(DIALOG_STATE_PROPERTY);`. Because you define your dialogs with `this.dialogs = new DialogSet(this.dialogState);`, every dialog you `add` to `this.dialogs` already gets the correct context and dialogState, as it should--you just need to use it in your dialogs.
2. It could also be that somewhere in your dialogs, you're calling `endDialog` or `cancelAllDialogs` prematurely.

If this doesn't solve your issue, post the code for one of the dialogs giving you trouble and I can help you troubleshoot this further.